# GridBagLayout component stretched

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have created a `GridBagLayout` where I have added different components:

```
private static void setMyConstraints(GridBagConstraints c, int gridx, int gridy, int anchor) {
          c.gridx = gridx;  //column
          c.gridy = gridy;  //row
          c.anchor = anchor;//position
          c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,5);  //top left bottom right padding
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       }
setMyConstraints(constraints,0,0,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(namelabel,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,1,0,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(name,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,0,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(genderlabel,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,0,2,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(gender,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(optionlabel,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,1,2,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(option,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,0,3,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(addrlabel,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,0,4,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(addr,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,0,5,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(alabel,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,0,6,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(a,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,1,5,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(blabel,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,1,6,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(b,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,2,5,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(clabel,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,2,6,GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        panel1.add(c,constraints);
        
        setMyConstraints(constraints,0,7,GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST);
        panel1.add(dOkButton,constraints);
        setMyConstraints(constraints,1,7,GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST);
        panel1.add(dClearButton,constraints);
```

Whenever the combo box for gender is stretched to wrap the text the component at same x position also get stretched, if addr. textarea is also increased column the component at same position x stretched.

This is the current output:

[ok button, a textfiled and namelabel is tretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nmDQ.jpg)

Intended output:

[even though the component like combobox stretched or add text area increased, the other component at same x position must not stretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK0jJ.jpg)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

First column seems to be set as "Grow" and it's weight may be set to "1.0".

If all of the column weights are set as "0.0", they won't be streched:

```
gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
```